# Mysql complex group by student mark

Tags: mysql

My table

```
student_id     Mark
-------------------
    1          50
    2          10
    3          20
    4          40
```

I want a query to show the % reached by marks like following

```
marks          reach_percentage
-------------------------------
 10                100%
 20                 75%     
 40                 50%
 50                 25%
```

It needs to be like 
mark 10 reached by all student so 100%,
mark 20 reached by 3 student so 75%,
mark 40 reached by 2 student so 50%,
mark 50 reached by 1 student so 25%. Percentage should be calculated by number of students reached with total number of students.
help me to solve this task. thanks.

Comment: How do you want those percentages to be calculated?

Comment: Edited my question and that may answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:-

```
SELECT a.Mark, (COUNT(DISTINCT b.student_id) / total_count) * 100
FROM marks_table a
INNER JOIN marks_table b
ON a.Mark <= b.Mark
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(Mark) AS total_count
    FROM marks_table
) Sub1
GROUP BY Mark;
```

SQL fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93e4df/3

Comment: Seems there is a problem If adding one more student with mark 20

Comment: Amended to sort that. Should be OK now